# Buffer Overflow payload via text file

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I have a vulnerable C program that copies a text file from one folder to another.
If we increase the text to more than 2048 characters, we get a buffer overflow.

Now, I would like to insert my payload through this text file containing `NOP+shell+RET ADD`

However, when it reads the file, it considers the text to be in ASCII and stores individual characters in the memory.

How can I insert my payload through this text?

```
int copy_file(const char* src_name, const char* dst_name){
    char buf[2048], *p1, *p2;
    FILE *src_file, *dst_file;
    int c;
    if (link(src_name, dst_name) == 0) {
            unlink(src_name);
            return 0;
    } else {
            src_file = fopen(src_name, "r");
            if (src_file == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open source file: %s\n",
                            src_name);
                    return 1;
            }
            p1 = buf;
            while ((c = fgetc(src_file)) != EOF) {
                   *p1 = c;
                    p1++;
            }

            fclose(src_file);

            dst_file = fopen(dst_name, "w");
            if (dst_file == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open destination file: %s\n",
                            dst_name);
                    return 1;
            }
            p2 = buf;
            while (p2 != p1) {
                    fputc(*p2, dst_file);
                    p2++;
            }

            fclose(dst_file);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(fgets(buf, sizeof buf, src_file)) fputs(buf, dst_file);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY You are missing the point.

Comment: @immibis Insert will be in OP favorite place. Note that the condition has not been presented.

Comment: How can i insert 0x90....shellcode ...ret address in my text file ?  basically all i can do is create a text file and pass as arguement.....eg.  ./submit myfile.txt

Comment: Have you consider open two files simultaneously and using read() and write() functions? It would make your program much shorter, you could avoid buffer overflow for bigger files.
It would be much easier to put shellcode:
unsigned char code = 0x90; and then write it to file.

Comment: @MarcinKajzler The asker knows perfectly well that the program is insecure. The asker is asking **how to exploit the program**. The asker presumably did not write the program, and is not allowed to modify it. This is a fairly common practical homework assignment to demonstrate how buffer overflow attacks work.

Comment: @immibis  exactly... I know exactly where to insert my retadd in my text file....fr eg xff\x90\x12\x34
 
The problem I am facing is when i submit this text file....
It goes to memroy  as  separate... "\"  "x" "9" "0"  and not as a whole "\x90"

Comment: If you want to put non-ascii bytes into your file try using echo -n -e \\xff\\x90\\x12\\x34 > sourceFile

Comment: hey thanks....i did it with fprint(*p, "\x90...")   it works !

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) indent consistently,  Never use tabs for indenting.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.  3) do not use 'magic' numbers (2048)  instead use a `enum` statement or `#define` statement to give the 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.  4) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put non-ascii bytes into your file try using `echo -n -e \\xff\\x90\\x12\\x34 > sourceFile` or you can use something like `fprint(*p, "\x90...")`